# Lint Staged does not access subfolders

Tags: reactjs, eslint, create-react-app, prettier, lint-staged

I'm running the `npx lint-staged` command and noticed that if I have the following tree:

```
src 
 /sub-folder-x
  - file-x
 /sub-folder-y
  - file-y
```

The `eslint` and `prettier` cannot find files in subfolders.

How do I get the stage to run on all subfolders and files of it?

[image]

.lintstagedrc.json

```
{
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": ["prettier --check", "eslint"]
}
```

✖ prettier --check:

```
[warn] src/App.test.tsx
[warn] src/App.tsx
[warn] src/index.tsx
[warn] src/reportWebVitals.ts
[warn] Code style issues found in the above file(s). Forgot to run Prettier?
```

✖ eslint:

```
/POC/uber-web/src/App.test.tsx
/POC/uber-web/src/App.tsx
/POC/uber-web/src/index.tsx
/POC/uber-web/src/reportWebVitals.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your file pattern string in `.lintstagedrc.json` is wrong. Try remove dot before bracket and put it before each file extension definition like this:

```
{
   "src/**/*{.js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx}": ["prettier --check", "eslint"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lint-staged along with husky, you can simply change the directory in the git-hook.

```
cd ./client && npx lint-staged
```

And the package.json should be

```
"lint-staged": {
  "*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": [
    "prettier --write",
    "eslint -c .eslintrc.json --fix"
  ]
}
```